# Add Icon to ".exe" while building with SCONS

Tags: c, icons, exe, scons, ico

I am working with C and building my project with Scons.

My Sconstruct

```
Program("bin/output", [Glob("src/*.c")])
```

This gives me output.exe.

How can I add an icon to my .exe file with SCons?

Comment: As you mention `.exe` files I assume you're building for Windows? Then you need to create a *resource* file that needs to be built and linked into your application.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes, I have a '.ico' file. I wanted a way to add it to my exe file through Scons

Comment: You need an **`.rc`** file to define the icon resource. Please [read more about resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/resources) (especially [icon resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/icons)). I also recommend you do some research of your own.

Comment: Adding to the above. Once you create a .rc file, you can just add that to the sources you've specified to your Program()..